# Recursive Parent Child Relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like

```
SourceClass | TargetClass | SourceID | TargetID
------------------------------------------------
A           | B           | 2         | 2
B           | C           | 2         | 2
C           | D           | 2         | 3
D           | E           | 2         | 4
B           | C           | 3         | 3
```

I am trying to define query with no success using which if i specify any of the child/parent SourceClass or SourceID it should return all the parents and child of that value.

For example: If I specify SourceClass = B and SourceID = 2.

It should return all the linked child and parent of SourceClass= B with SourceID = 2.

For above value it should return

```
SourceClass | TargetClass | SourceID | TargetID
------------------------------------------------
A           | B           | 2         | 2
B           | C           | 2         | 2
C           | D           | 2         | 3
D           | E           | 2         | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use adjacency list model to get HIERARCHICAL DATA.
check this [link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) reference